# Residue class of prime powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Assume $c(n)$ an arithmetic function that is multiplicative and has period $q$. For a fixed prime number $p$ with $p\mid q$ write $A_d=\{m\in\mathbb{N}:p^m\equiv d\text{ (mod }q)\}$ for $d\in\{0,1,\dotsc,p-1\}$. Prove that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=0}^\infty c(p^m)p^{-ms}=\sum_{d=0}^{p-1}c(d)\sum_{m\in A_d}p^{-ms}.
\end{equation}
I got a problem with the upper bound of the first sum on the right being $p-1$ instead of $q-1$.
The whole thing would be clear if we could always find $d\in\{0,1,\dotsc,p-1\}$ with $p^m\equiv d\text{ (mod }q)$, but as there are counterexamples (see answers below), this is the wrong way.

Comment: Please ask a new question, in stead of editing your question to ask something completely different.

Comment: And the bound should indeed be $q-1$, not $p-1$.

Comment: About your new question : If $c(n)$ is multiplicative and $q$-periodic then it is completely multiplicative and it is a Dirichlet character modulo $d |q$

Comment: I'm sorry for that, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't think so, as not necessarily $c(n)=0$ if $(n,q)>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $q=4$, $m=1$ and $p=2$.

Or $q=6$, $m=1$, $p=3$.

Comment: Damned, you are right. So I got to dig deeper, I will state the actual problem.

Comment: I haven't tried plugging in any numbers yet, but something tells me that the situation might be radically different with odd primes.

Comment: See my edit. Such an integer $d$ will quite often not exist; certainly never if $m=1$. In fact there are counterexamples for *any* composite $q>3$. Also for any $m>0$, and also for any prime $p$.